# NSZombie Enabled but Still No Debug Info

Tags: ios, xcode, nszombie

All of a sudden an app I've been developing is no longer outputting debug info to the console even though NSZombie is properly configured.  I'm on Xcode 4.5 and tried this on iOS 5 and 6.  Any clues what may be wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some hints:
- Ensure that project in Debug mode: Product - Edit scheme... => Build configuration = Debug
- Add Exception break point: Switch to Breakpoint Navigator and Add Exception Breakpoint [Exception: Objective-C]