# NSZombieEnabled not working

Tags: ios, nszombieenabled

I've set `NSZombieEnabled` to `YES` in my scheme but still no debug info. I am using Xcode 4.6.3.

I've read this question but it does not solve my issue: [NSZombie Enabled but Still No Debug Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12716737/nszombie-enabled-but-still-no-debug-info).

Here is the crash log,

```
-[MODELNode nodeList]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1315170
2013-12-16 12:30:29.990 OHI Control[6198:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MODELNode nodeList]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1315170'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x311c32a3 0x3906397f 0x311c6e07 0x311c5531 0x3111cf68 0x1a2273 0x333fc547 0x333fd789 0x333f4add 0x333f53eb 0x333f27d3 0x333fc685 0x333fcb3d 0x333e375f 0x32fce803 0x32d78d8b 0x32d78929 0x32d7985d 0x32d79243 0x32d79051 0x32fd48eb 0x311986cd 0x311969c1 0x31196d17 0x31109ebd 0x31109d49 0x34cd32eb 0x3301f301 0x2f15 0x3949ab20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

How do I get this working correctly?

Comment: What is the error, you are debugging for? NSZombies enables you to pick only those errors where you try to refer deallocated objects.

Comment: The log prints that I'm sending an invalid message to an instance but doesn't print where did this actually happen i.e. it doesn't point out  to the code snippet.

Comment: Use break point to debug it

Comment: Go to the Breakpoint Navigator in Xcode and add All Exception Breakpoint. It may help you. Also, post the whole error message here, someone may help you.

Comment: Sorry Puneet I haven't understood what do you mean by add "All Exception Breakpoint". Can you please elaborate.

Comment: attached the crash log to my question . Thanks

Comment: Click on your project there will be symbol of breakpoint in upper menu. When you select this there will be + button in yhe bottom of that menu use this button and add all Exception breakpoint

Comment: @Adi: Or if you are not able to view the breakpoint in upper menu as Ashutosh suggested, Go to View->Navigators->Show Breakpoint Navigator. This will be visible on the left side of XCode along with Project Navigator. There you can see + sign at the bottom, which is used to add Exception Breakpoint for all exceptions

Comment: Cheers Ashutosh Mishra. That worked!! Thanks to Puneet as well. Xcode is now pointing out to the crash location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For adding Exception Break Point I am adding here images to explain how.

[image: First image]
[image: Second image]

[image: Third image]

[image: Fourth Image]

That's All. Hope this helps.